# Anyway to use Percona's keyring_vault.so with MySQL Community Edition

Tags: mysql, encryption, percona

Percona Distro of MySQL has a plugin **keyring_vault.so** that enables InnoDB's encryption to stay on Hashi Vault and can be rotated periodically writing the new encryption key to the Vault.

MySQL Enterprise has HashiCorp Keyring plug-in which comes with only enterprise edition.
I know that Percona's Edition is free to download and install and only the support is what we need to purchase. However the firm that I work for is more inclined on using MySQL Community Edition.

I'm wondering if there's any way to use Percona's **keyring_vault.so** with **MySQL Community Edition**.

The version of **MySQL Community is 8.0.20**

Any help suggestion is greatly appreciated.